# How do I forward all data from one connection to another (NodeJS)?

Tags: node.js, forwarding

I want a server to listen for a connection from 100.0.0.0:3000.  When the connection occurs, it should then open up a new connection to 200.0.0.0:3000 and maintain exact data forwarding from the first connection to the second one.

Note, this is not HTTP.

I am not an expert with NodeJS's connection utilities, so the attempt I have is an error-fraught mess that's simply not working (I can show you if I like).  I'm sure there is a simple way to do this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this proxy: https://github.com/gonzalo123/nodejs.tcp.proxy/blob/master/proxy.js.

Really simple. Does the job :)

Comment: Cool proxy, but it's actually crashing for me after a few data transfers.  I think I may need to set the data type to binary or increase the buffer... not really sure.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [HAProxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/) or [IPTables](https://serverfault.com/questions/140622/how-can-i-port-forward-with-iptables) to forward ports.